# Error: `No handler found` with Base64 for Paperclip 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I'm facing with problem to upload images as base64.

Everything works fine with paperclip version **5.1.0 or lower**

My model:

```
do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :image

has_attached_file :image
```

My controller action:

```
def update
  current_appointment.update(update_params)

  redirect_to check_in_flow.next_step_path
end

private

def update_params
  params.require(:appointment).permit(:image)
end
```

My params:

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"appointment"=>{"image"=>"data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgo..."}, "controller"=>"my_controller", "action"=>"update"} permitted: false>
```

---

After upgrading version I'm always getting:

```
 Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError:
   No handler found for "data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgo..."
```

Is anyone got similar problem, maybe new version not support base64 anymore ?

Paperclip version: **5.2.0 or newest**

Rails version: **5.1.4**

Ruby version: **2.3.4p301**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ran into a similar issue after upgrading and found the solution was to add the following to `config/initializers/paperclip.rb`:

```
Paperclip::DataUriAdapter.register
```

Looks like this happened prior to 5.2.0

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/pull/2435